# Why does my code breakdown whenever I use a value of n>1 i.e. number of structure varibale in my C code?

Tags: c, for-loop, struct

I'm an amateur programmer, I've been trying to create a structure with scanf and printf using loops but my code breaks down whenever I try to read for more than 1 variable.

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct list
{
    char name;
    int age;
    float height;
};

int main()
{
    int n=2;
    struct list s[n];
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
    printf("Enter the name of %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%c",&s[i].name);
    printf("Enter the age of %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%d",&s[i].age);
    printf("Enter the height of %d:",i+1);
    scanf("%f",&s[i].height);
    }
    
    for(int i=0;i<=n-1;i++)
    {
    printf("Name is %c\n",s[i].name);
    printf("Age is %d\n",s[i].age);
    printf("Height is %f\n",s[i].height);   
    }
        
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Enter the name of 1:A
Enter the age of 1:25
Enter the height of 1:5.5
Enter the name of 2:Enter the age of 2:24
Enter the height of 2:5.6
Name is A
Age is 25
Height is 5.500000
Name is

Age is 24
Height is 5.600000
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please add text output as formatted text in the question. No need to post screenshots of text where 95% of the area are not even related anyway.

Comment: [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5240789)

Comment: `scanf("%c", ...)` will not work as you expect. Change format to `" %c"` (note leading space).

Comment: Also always check what `scanf` [***returns***](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: Side note: the more idiomatic way to write your `for` loop would be `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`

Comment: Aside: `i <= n-1` is unidiomatic, use `i < n`